# can't understand what is wrong with my simple class for img

Tags: css

All i want to do is apply a border-radius to an image. Here is the css for it (i have very similar css in another project that works absolutely fine).

```
.testimonial-pic img {
width:48px; 
height:48px;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}​
```

I thought, maybe there was something inherit in the html that was causing it to fail, but can't spot anything immediately obvious there either.

```
<blockquote class="testimonial">
<p>You don’t need to see his identification. 
These aren’t the droids you’re looking   for. 
He can go about his business. Move along.</p>
 </blockquote>
 <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  <img class="testimonial-pic" src="carmen_villadar_thumb.jpg"   />
  <p class="testimonial-author">Obi-Wan Kenobi | <span>Jedi Master</span></p>
```

I've tried to change the order in which the css is applied. I have also inspected my surrounding css and can't see anything that should conflict, especially considering the fact that i'm not applying any css to any other image properties, i've also named an independent class, so can't see why this isn't or shouldn't work.

Here is a link to the live page, just in case: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3417415/testimonials/carmen_villadar.html

Comment: In your demo the resources (the CSS files) aren't being loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rule should be applied to `img.testimonial-pic`. You are currently applying the rule to images inside an element with class `.testimonial-pic`.

Comment: Can't believe i made such a rookie mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. It appears to be working now, but seems to have affected the css in the div below, but i shall look into that. thank you anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

change your `css` from

```
.testimonial-pic img {}
```

to

```
.testimonial-pic {}
```

your `img` has a class so appending another img to your class is targeting the wrong element

Answer (score 0):

`.testimonial-pic img` Specifies that you are looking for a container with class `testimonial-pic` that contains an image. In your HTML you have `<img class="testimonial-pic" src="carmen_villadar_thumb.jpg"   />` which is an image with class `testimonial-pic`. You either need to wrap the image or change your css to

```
img.testimonial-pic {
width:48px; 
height:48px;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}​
```